# How to retrieve files from 2 different projects in the same solution without hard code the path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, file-upload

I have 2 projects under 1 solution, 1 project called adminsite, and another 1 called publicsite. What i want to achieve is, i want to retrieve some files in publicsite sub folders and use those files in adminsite, but i dont wanna hard code the path, i mean i want to get relative path, how to do it? any example would be great, thank before.

note : usually i retrieve file path this way, but this file is located under 1 project sub folder.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="filelink"
     NavigateUrl='<%#"~/files/attachment/mrfdocument/" + Eval("mrfdocument")%>'/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you should be able to use relative path by using `~/../publicsite/files/attachment/mrfdocument/` to go up one level. However it will depend on actual URLs and location on server.

Comment: i think your code might work. but i have a question, since i don't know the actual path on client computer, so i can not hard code the path. but by using relative path is n't it going to be ok?

Comment: Client computer or server? The physical path does not matter anyway though, only URLs matter. If someone can install adminsite and publicsite into a differently named virtual folders you will have to add a configuration setting for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

When adding existing file, choose add as link .

But from your question it sound that you need to create new project that contain all the code that both project used. 
something like `Utils` project

Comment: actually what i want is "i am storing user picture files under publicsite subfolder, and i want to retrieve and use those files in some aspx files in adminsite"

Comment: @HendraLim in that case you can have project that contain all the resources - resource manager